# How to retrieve previous NYSE trading day in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get the previous trading day in relation to a given trading day. To start I am simply trying to make a function which returns the previous business day when given a date, like so:

```
import datetime

def get_previous_trading_day(day):
    day = pd.to_datetime(day)
    previous_trading_day = day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return previous_trading_day
```

But when I call my function and print the current vs previous date, the previous date is not the previous day:

```
2021-05-01 curr
1885-02-22 00:00:00 prev
```

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the calculation to use `pd.tseries.offsets.BDay` instead, you will get the previous business day (instead of the day before).  I realise this will not work for bank holidays where no trading occurs.  Your function works well when I try it for returning the previous day's date.

```
def get_previous_trading_day(day):
    day = pd.to_datetime(day)
    previous_trading_day = day - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1)

    return previous_trading_day
```

Calling the function for tomorrow's date will return Friday's date:

```
get_previous_trading_day("2022-05-16")
#Out: Timestamp('2022-05-13 00:00:00')
```

For your returned date, you may have put a date format that was not read correctly by the `pd.to_datetime`.  If you require a specific format, add the kwarg `format=` to this.